# i am getting error in this code snippet , i don't know why

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

```cpp
bool check(vector<int> &nums)
{
    int *big = &nums[0];
    int n = nums.size(), x = 0;

    for (int i = n - 2; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (nums[i] > x)
        {
            x = nums[i];
        }
    }

    big = &x;
    if (big != &nums[n - 1])
    {
        big++;
    }
    rotate(&nums[0], big, &nums[n]);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i - 1] > nums[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-underflow on address 0x7ffd698133fc at pc 0x00000034d07d bp 0x7ffd69813370 sp 0x7ffd69813368
```

getting this error

Comment: Once you do `big = &x` it no longer points to an element of `nums` and can't be used to `rotate` the array `nums`. All arguments must be iterators to the same range.

Comment: `x` is (a copy of) the value of an element in the vector. `&x` is not the location of an element in the vector.

Comment: What this code should do? `check` doesn't say anything useful. Is this valid MCVE: https://godbolt.org/z/jG4nP18sd ?

Comment: The code has several undefined names. Don't ask people to guess at what they're supposed to refer to.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cTxjYM7z9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::rotate` requires that all three arguments refer to the same container. But in your code the pointer `big` holds the address of an unrelated variable `x`.

Seems clear that you were trying to write this code

```
    int* big = &nums[0];
    int n=nums.size();

    for(int i = n-2 ; i > -1 ;i--)
    {
        if(nums[i] > *big)
        {
            big = &nums[i];
        }
    }
```

Assigning to `x` from `nums` and then assigning to `big` the address of `x` is not the same thing at all as assigning directly to `big` the address of an element in `nums`.

Comment: Thank you for your response,   now I will be able to resolve the issue.